# sublime text snippet "unexpected end of data"

Tags: sublimetext3, code-snippets

I've created the following snippet on sublime text:

```
<snippet>
<content><!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8'>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html></content>
<tabTrigger>!</tabTrigger>
</snippet>
```

But when attempting to save it, I get the following error:

"error parsing snippet xml: unexpected end of data in file"

Why is this?

Yours sincerely and thank you for all your help.

Answer (score 2):

You may have accidentally removed the `<![CDATA[` and `]]` portions of the sample snippet XML; as a result sublime can't figure out where the content of the snippet ends.

You want something more like this:

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8'>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    $0
</body>
</html>]]></content>
    <tabTrigger>!</tabTrigger>
</snippet>
```

Note that I've added a `$0` into the snippet inside the body tags; that tells Sublime where to drop the cursor after it has expanded the snippet, so that you're ready to continue editing the HTML document; you may or may not want to have that depending on what you're trying to do.